# Rendering SSRS charts at lower resolution when exporting to PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm running some reports on SSRS 2012 and they render fine in the web interface, but when I export them to PDF the patterns in the graph are rendered with too much detail (i.e. there's meant to be ~10 vertical lines in the pattern but there is more like 200). Is there any way to overcome this?

Cheers in advance

Edit: picture below. The left graph is what renders in the web interface, the right is what appears in the PDF (if you zoom in further on the right the pattern is the same as the left one)

[image]

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are seeing... Is there a way you can edit the question with a screenshot of what it happening

Comment: Have added one for you :)

Comment: possibly an odd question here but are you using windows 7?

Comment: On a side note have you tried setting image consolidation to false? Also you could try a fun little work around in setting the background of the graph to a gradient color from white to smoke white (two most similar whites) this should add a proportion factor to the graph. Its a work around I used with 2008-r2 as it used to happen all the time with 2008 but supposedly they fixed it in sp2 and all subsequent releases.

Answer (score 0):

I have done few changes in the `Reportserver.config` file in order to overcome that issue. Normally you need to play with the configuration settings for PDF render. Insert the attached code in the config file PDF render section and Adjust the `DpiX` and `DpiY` values based on the export output.

I have set the below property, it works fine in SSRS 2014.

```
    <DpiX>125</DpiX>

<DpiY>125</DpiY>
```

Refer [to this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281(v=SQL.100).aspx) for more details.